# What all APIs are affected by {$IOCHECKS OFF}?

Tags: delphi, file-io, error-handling, compiler-directives

We have some ancient Delphi code (might have even originated as Turbo Pascal code) that uses `{$I-}`, aka `{$`[`IOCHECKS`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=%24IOChecks)
 `OFF}`, which makes the code use [IOResult](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=IOResult) instead of exceptions for disk I/O errors.

I want to get rid of the `{$I-}` and bring this code forward into the 1990s, but to do that, I'd like to know what all is affected by `{$IOCHECKS OFF}`. Does this only affect the crufty old built-in I/O functions like AssignFile / Reset / Rewrite / Append / CloseFile? Or does it affect more modern things like TFileStream as well? More importantly, what else might be affected that I'm not thinking of? ([Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=%24IOChecks) suggests that it also affects MkDir and RmDir. If it affects those, there have to be more.)

The Delphi 2007 Help topic "Input output checking (Delphi)" (`ms-help://borland.bds5/devcommon/compdirsinput_outputchecking_xml.html`) says that this affects "I/O procedure[s]", and that "I/O procedures are described in the Delphi Language Guide." This doesn't help much, since CodeGear has never shipped a Language Guide, and the last time Borland shipped one was Delphi 5.

Which functions and classes behave differently under `{$I-}`?

---

**EDIT:** The accepted answer gives some great background, but here's the quick summary in alphabetized list form: `{$IOCHECKS OFF}` *only* affects the following routines from the System unit.

- Append
- BlockRead
- BlockWrite
- ChDir
- CloseFile
- Eof
- Eoln
- Erase
- FilePos
- FileSize
- Flush
- MkDir
- Read
- Readln
- Rename
- Reset
- Rewrite
- RmDir
- Seek
- SeekEof
- SeekEoln
- SetLineBreakStyle
- Truncate
- Write
- Writeln

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `$I` is a compiler directive, it can only affect compiler-generated code, and it can only affect code that actually gets compiled.

For those two reasons, it *cannot* affect things like `TFileStream`. It's a class in *Classes.pas*, which is a unit you don't compile. Any code in it is not affected by the `$I` directive. Furthermore, the compiler doesn't treat that class specially in any way. It's just another ordinary class.

The `$I` directive affects the language built-in functions that you've mentioned. The compiler generates calls to those functions specially. It also affects calls to `write`, `writeln`, and `readln`. It should also affect `BlockRead` and `BlockWrite`.

You can check the source code. Anything that calls `SetInOutRes` is susceptible to `$I`. That includes functions that open files (`Append`, `Reset`, and `Rewrite`), as well as anything else that accepts a parameter of type `file` or `TextFile` (`Flush`, `BlockRead`, `BlockWrite`, `Erase`, `FilePos`, `Seek`, `FileSize`, `Read`, `Readln`, `Write`, `Writeln`, `Rename`, `Eof`, `SeekEof`, `Eoln`, `SeekEol`, `Truncate`, `SetLineBreakStyle`, and `CloseFile`). Also, anything that calls `InOutError` (`ChDir`, `MkDir`, amd `RmDir`).

Notably absent from the list is `AssignFile`. That function doesn't actually do any I/O. It just sets up the file record so that `Append`, `Reset`, and `Rewrite` will know what to do.

---

I should point out that looking at the source code is just inference. The `$I` directive controls whether the compiler will insert calls to the `__IOTest` function in your own code after you call certain other functions. That function checks the value of `InOutRes`, and if it's not zero, it raises a run-time error (which may yield an exception if *SysUtils* is included in your program). We can't check the source code to *directly* find out what functions are affected by `$I` (since it's only called in compiler-generated code), so we're really just looking for which functions *set* `InOutRes`, with the assumption that they wouldn't bother doing that if they didn't know the compiler would check for it afterward.

Comment: Sweet - good to know how to track these down (and good grief, are there a lot of `_Read*` and `_Write*` methods in there!). It looks like you missed three, though: `SetLineBreakStyle`, `SeekEof`, and `SeekEoln`.

Comment: Also of note is that this only affects routines in the System unit. Nothing else calls `SetInOutRes` or `InOutError`.

Comment: All the `_Read*` and `_Write*` are there because `Read` and `Write` are compile magic. The compiler inserts a call to a specialized function for *each parameter* you pass to `Read` or `Write`. It inserts calls to `__IOTest` if `$I` is enabled.